# Processing: Array in If statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, fonts, processing

I'm a processing beginner. Ideally, I'd like to randomly change font by each word when it's showed. However, because of my lack of appreciation for JAVA, I'm just trying to change each font by specific numbers according to array "nums" for now. Could you advice me excellent idea to change font by each word?

```
PFont f1, f2, f3;
String message = "transText 2013";
int[] nums = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13};
float r,g,b = 0;
float rr = 0.5;
float gg = 0.1;
float bb = 0.3;
float n;


void setup(){
  size(800,400);
  frameRate(20);
  nums = new int[6];
  f1 = createFont("Arial-Black", 16, true);
  f2 = createFont("Courier", 16, true);
}

void draw(){

rr = rr + 0.02;
gg = gg + 0.02;
bb = bb + 0.02;

background(35);

r = map(random(rr),0,1,100,255);
g = map(random(gg),0,1,100,255);
b = map(random(bb),0,1,100,255);
color n = color(r,g,b);
fill(n);
// The first character is at pixel 10.
int x = 50; 
for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
  if(i == nums){
  textFont(f1);
  }else{
  textFont(f2);
  };

  textSize(random(12,120));
  // Each character is displayed one at a time with the charAt() function.
  text(message.charAt(i),x,height/2);
  // All characters are spaced 50 pixels apart.
  x += textWidth(message.charAt(i)); 
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you are trying to achieve. Could be more specific and elaborate on your problem?

Comment: This program is mere practice of using String, therefore there is no specific purpose or goal as a project. Now, I'm just technically trying to change each word's font when it's showed. For example, like this _t_**r**n... and also if it's possible, I'd like to randomly change the word's font every frame. I hope this explanation will make understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(i == nums){
```

You compare an integer value (number) with an arrays of integers (a lot of numbers).
It is totally impossible.

You can compare an integer value with an ELEMENT of the array.
For example:

```
if(i==nums[i])
```

Or you can see whether an array contains a value.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(nums);
if(list.contains(i))
```

Comment: Thank you for quick and sharp advise. I understand that I just need to learn basic Java syntax beforehand. I'll try both way in few days.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jcaptcha [RandomFontGenerator](http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/apidocs/1.0/com/octo/captcha/component/image/fontgenerator/RandomFontGenerator.html)

Comment: Thank you for accurate reference. This method seems surely work in processing. I'll try this later.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all, especially constantlerner. I just solved the problem by RandomFontGenerator Method. Following is a final code. I'll keep work on this program for changing each words font differently. Thank you again.

```
PFont f1, f2, f3, fontR;
String message = "transText 2013";
float r,g,b = 0;
float rr = 0.5;
float gg = 0.1;
float bb = 0.3;
float n;
int randomFont;

void setup(){
  size(800,200);
  frameRate(20);
  f1 = createFont("Arial-Black", 16, true);
  f2 = createFont("Courier", 16, true);
  f3 = createFont("FuturaStd-Light", 16, true);

}

void draw(){

rr = rr + 0.02;
gg = gg + 0.02;
bb = bb + 0.02;

background(35);

  float rF = random(1,10); // Picking random number 1 to 10(depending on how much range you want)
  randomFont = int(rF); // rF into int

  // Separating range by if-statement in 3 parts
  if(rF < 3){
  fontR = f1;}
  else if(rF > 3 && rF < 6){
  fontR = f2;}
  else{
  fontR = f3;}

// fontR into textFont
textFont(fontR);


r = map(random(rr),0,1,100,255);
g = map(random(gg),0,1,100,255);
b = map(random(bb),0,1,100,255);
color n = color(r,g,b);
fill(n);
// The first character is at pixel 50.
int x = 30;

for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) { 
  textSize(random(12,120));
  // Each character is displayed one at a time with the charAt() function.
  text(message.charAt(i),x,170);
  // All characters are spaced 10 pixels apart.
  x += textWidth(message.charAt(i));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RiTa](http://rednoise.org/rita) library:

```
import rita.*;

RiText[] rts;
String[] fonts = { "arial","times","courier" };

void setup() {

   rts = RiText.createLetters(this,"transText 2013",5,30,100);
}

void draw() {

  background(255);
  for (int i = 0; i < rts.length; i++) {   
    rts[i].fill(RiText.randomColor());
    rts[i].font(fonts[(int)random(fonts.length)], 14);
  }
  RiText.drawAll();
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is what I wanted. Thank you for telling me great library.